# Pyspark checking if any of the rows is greater then zero

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to filter out the rows that have zero values for all the columns in a list.

Suppose for example we have the follwing df,

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(0, 1, 1, 2,1), (0, 0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1 ,1)], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
+---+---+---+---+---+                                                           
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  1|  2|  1|
|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|
|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

and the list of columns is ['a', 'b', 'd'] so the filtered dataframe should be,

```
+---+---+---+---+---+                                                           
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  1|  2|  1|
|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

This is what I have tried,

```
df = df.withColumn('total', sum(df[col] for col in ['a', 'b', 'd']))
df = df.filter(df.total > 0).drop('total')
```

This works fine for small datasets but fails with the following error if the col_list is very long with the following error.

> ava.lang.StackOverflowErrorat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveLambdaVariables.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$ResolveLambdaVariables$$resolve(higher...

I can think of a pandas udf solution but my df is very large and that might be a bottleneck.

**Edit:**

When using @Psidom's answer I get the following error

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2508.filter.
>   : java.lang.StackOverflowError
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.references(Expression.scala:88)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$references$1.apply(Expression.scala:88)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$references$1.apply(Expression.scala:88)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the columns as **array** to a **UDF** and then check if all values are zeros or not and then apply the filter:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, array, col

all_zeros_udf = udf(lambda arr: arr.count(0) == len(arr), BooleanType())

df = spark.createDataFrame([(0, 1, 1, 2,1), (0, 0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1 ,1)], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

df
.withColumn('all_zeros', all_zeros_udf(array('a', 'b', 'd'))) # pass the columns as array
.filter(~col('all_zeros')) # Filter the columns where all values are NOT zeros
.drop('all_zeros')  # Drop the column
.show()
```

Result:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  1|  2|  1|
|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks, do you think using a udf when we have millions of rows and thousands of columns a good idea ?

Comment: Depends on how you use it. We use many udfs to process TB's of data every day.

Answer (score 3):

[`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) could be useful here:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(0, 1, 1, 2,1), (0, 0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1 ,1)], 
     ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
cols = ['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Use `reduce` to create the filter expression:

```
from functools import reduce
predicate = reduce(lambda a, b: a | b, [df[x] != 0 for x in cols])

print(predicate)
# Column<b'(((NOT (a = 0)) OR (NOT (b = 0))) OR (NOT (d = 0)))'>
```

Then `filter` with the `predicate`:

```
df.where(predicate).show()
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  1|  2|  1|
|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: This only works if you have a small number of columns, in my case where the number of columns are in thousands I get an error, the log of error is added in the question

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different solution. Haven't tried on the large set of columns, please let me know if this works.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(0, 1, 1, 2,1), (0, 0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1 ,1)], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
df.show()

+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  1|  2|  1|
|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|
|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+

df = df.withColumn("Concat_cols" , F.concat(*list_of_cols)) # concat the list of columns 
df.show()

+---+---+---+---+---+-----------+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|Concat_cols|
+---+---+---+---+---+-----------+
|  0|  1|  1|  2|  1|        012|
|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|        000|
|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|        101|
+---+---+---+---+---+-----------+

pattern =  '0' * len(list_of_cols) 

df1 = df.where(df['Concat_cols'] != pattern) # pattern will be 0's and the number will be equal to length of the columns list.
df1.show()

    +---+---+---+---+---+-----------+
    |  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|Concat_cols|
    +---+---+---+---+---+-----------+
    |  0|  1|  1|  2|  1|        012|
    |  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|        101|
    +---+---+---+---+---+-----------+
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but not sure if storing such a long string in a df that has millions of rows is a good idea.I think performance wise a UDF would be better

Comment: Sure if you dont want to have a new dataframe with those string data, then you can combine those two into a single line of code. `df1 = df.where(F.concat(*list_of_cols) != pattern)`

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is just to check `0` occurrence in all columns and the lists are causing problem then possibly combine them `1000` at a time and then test for non-zero occurrence.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# all or whatever columns you would like to test.
columns = df.columns 

# Columns required to be concatenated at a time.
split = 1000 

# list of 1000 columns concatenated into a single column
blocks = [F.concat(*columns[i*split:(i+1)*split]) 
            for i in range((len(columns)+split-1)//split)]

# where expression here replaces zeroes to check if the resultant string is blank or not.
(df.select("*")
    .where(F.regexp_replace(F.concat(*blocks).alias("concat"), "0", "") != "" )
    .show(10, False))
```